# How to use react-swipe to render many items within one slide?

Tags: reactjs

I am using React-swipe for a project. I follow the main example.

```
<div>
  <ReactSwipe
    className="carousel"
    swipeOptions={{ continuous: false }}
    ref={el => (reactSwipeEl = el)}
  >
    <div>PANE 1</div>
    <div>PANE 2</div>
    <div>PANE 3</div>
  </ReactSwipe>
  <button onClick={() => reactSwipeEl.next()}>Next</button>
  <button onClick={() => reactSwipeEl.prev()}>Previous</button>
</div>
```

But the result is that PANE1, PANE2, PANE3 all takes up the whole screen width. I want all PANE1, PANE2 and PANE3 have 60vw so that you see PANE1 and part of PANE2. What I want is Facebook like mobile carousel which is somehow like the following:

https://codesandbox.io/s/lrk6955l79?module=%2Fsrc%2FCarousel.js

Thank you.

Comment: Your are solved this task? In codesandbox I see PANE1 and part of PANE2

Answer (score 0):

In `src/components`, change `flex-basis` property of `CarouselSlot` from `80%` to something like `50%`. And if you want to change the starting point of the visible slides, you can play with `transform` property of `CarouselContainer`.